# Max number of annotation pin on mkmapview

Tags: iphone, xcode, mkmapview

I am making a application in which  i need to show annotations on map view .But whenever i pass the annotation pin with same lat lon value then i do not get all the callouts .
For example say my  latitude is 22.25455 and longitude is 72.324324  which i looped in for 10 times so i pass a plcemark array with 10 object and i get one annotation pin which is correct but when i click to get callout i do not get 10 callout but only get maximum 3 callout .

Is the problem with coding part or is is that maximum 3 callouts are allowed for same lat lon annotation pin .
Hope i am clear with  my question .

Answer (score 0):

MapKit allows you to have as many pins as you want at the same coordinate - but the problem is that other than the pins' shadows darkening, it looks like a single pin. And you can't select the different pins.

In other words: Don't add multiple pins to the same latitude and longitude!